# Azure: How to fix apt-get issues with the Azure Ubuntu Archive?

Tags: ubuntu, azure

On a new machine created with the 14.04LTS Azrue in the North Europe Datacenter, apt-get fails with the following issue:

```
azureuser@x:~$ sudo apt-get update
Err http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease

Err http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease

Err http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to azure.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to azure.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to azure.archive.ubuntu.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to azure.archive.ubuntu.com:http:

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I´ve also created another machine, same issue... How to best fix that? Seems a issue with the Azure Ubuntu Mirror...

Comment: What do you get when you stick this in your browser. http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  ... You should get the PGP key. If not your machine can't see that archive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to have been a temporary problem with the Ubuntu azure repo. It was down when I first tested it, but it's available now and I have no problem with a fresh VM. Try running `sudo apt-get update` again.

Comment: Thanks :). I´ve had it work and not work a number of times. Got the apt-get to run eventually. Still flaky though.

Comment: Instable again https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues/7048

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem, but it was security related.  Make sure to check your Network Security Group (NSG) rules.  It will need to allow outbound traffic on port 80 to communicate with  azure.archive.ubuntu.com.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. This seems to [have been a problem with Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/553765/failed-to-fetch-update-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts-trusty-tahr) but it still affects some versions of the 14.04 image on Azure. I suggest you use a newer version of the Ubuntu image such as

`b39f27a8b8c64d52b05eac6a62ebad85__Ubuntu_DAILY_BUILD-trusty-14_04_3-LTS-amd64-server-20151104-en-us-30GB`

rather than older ones like this:

`b39f27a8b8c64d52b05eac6a62ebad85__Ubuntu-14_04_1-LTS-amd64-server-20140927-en-us-30GB`

To see what images are available on Azure use:

`azure vm image list | grep Ubuntu`